# RCP: Editor with two views?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I want to create a topcomponent with two views. One simmilar to the form designer and one simmilar to the java souce editor.

In the upper left of the form designer are two buttons to switch between the views. This i need to implement, too.

Do you know a way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links to get you started:

A simple getting started:
http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/small_multiview_editor_experiment

A more complex tutorial:
http://blogs.oracle.com/vdblog/entry/part_1_xml_multiview_visual